# CentOS 5.4 (Final) - Can not bring up eth0

Tags: centos, linux-networking, centos5, local-area-network

I have CentOS 5.4 installed on my machine. Due to some reason I can not bring up wired connection. When I try to configure ip address through DHCP it fails and give the error "***no link present. Check cable?***"

I have checked all the things as per my understanding and came up with following information.

- Network cable is plugged properly and it is showing that link is up.
- I can assign the static ip address of the device and when i use **ifup** command works fine but network status is still disconnected.
- I have only one network card installed in system (Built-in)
- Computer Mother board model is Intel DH61HO

**How to bring up the network ?**

Comment: can you issue `ethtool <ifname>` and post the output?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this on the correct interface? Do an **ifconfig -a** and make sure that you are working on the correct interface in case that the card has multiple ports (eg. eth0)

Then create the equivalent file that should look similar this.

```
[root@mymachine ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPV6INIT="no"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR=192.168.10.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

After this restart network service to pick up the changes. If it doesn't work then check the log files.